# How to run a script when suspending/resuming? - Sony VAIO Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, suspend, etc

**Question:** How to assign a script to run when selecting the suspend option on the power menu?

**Context:**
I have a Sony VAIO laptop with an AMD Radeon graphics card. I would like to be able to disable/enable the discrete graphics card. I have no problem in doing this but it causes problems when suspending & resuming from suspend.

When the session is resumed from suspend (with the discrete DPU disabled), the fan will spin up uncontrollably, what I would like to do is edit the suspend script or assign a new script to the suspend option on the power menu. This is so I can re-enable the GPU before suspending.
[image: Power Menu]

**EDIT:**
After some research I think it has something to do with the files in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/`?

If I put a custom script in there would it be run when suspending and resuming from suspend?

How do I differentiate in the script between suspending/resuming?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are right. You have to write a script and save it to `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` (since 2015 systemd take care of that, before was `/etc/pm/sleep.d/`). The difference between suspending and resuming is given as a parameter to the script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
    suspend)
        # executed on suspend
        ;;
    resume) 
        # executed on resume
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
```

If you also want to do it for hibernate, the arguments would be `hibernate` and `thaw`.

Comment: I'd seen this in other scripts and was wondering on the specific requirements for such a script. Thank you :)

Comment: Hi, tried this on my Dell 5570 running ubuntu 14.04 to get it to turn my touchpad on, if I'd turned if off before suspending.   for some reason, the command     `tp_id=` (`)xinput list | grep -i touchpad | awk '{ print $7 }' | sed 's/id=//'(`)    is not returning the id, while this command does work from the command line.   Can you see any reason why it wouldn't?    For other purposes you script works great.     Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, in that previous comment, I tried to put backticks into the script fragment, but the minimarkdown language defeated me.   the ()'s are meant to be replaced by backticks

Comment: @LeoSimon Hey Leo, the comments are not the right place to discuss such a follow up question. I suggest you ask an entirely new question. This way a lot more people will see it and be able to help you :-)

Comment: You may need to use `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` instead.

Comment: For this to work in my system I had do make the target script executable. The available cases `suspend`, `resume`, etc are documented in `man pm-hibernate`

Answer (score 2):

On current Ubuntu versions which use `systemd`, you can put scripts (or links to scripts) into `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`.

Try to put this into `/usr/local/bin/test-sleep.sh` :

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

## This file (or a link to it) must be in /lib/systemd/system-sleep/

me=$(basename "$0")

case "$1" in
    pre)
        logger -t "$me" "Suspending: \$1=$1, \$2=$2" ;;
    post)
        logger -t "$me" "Resuming: \$1=$1, \$2=$2" ;;
esac
```

Then make it executable and put a link to it for systemd:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/test-sleep.sh
sudo ln -si /usr/local/bin/test-sleep.sh  /lib/systemd/system-sleep/
```

The script just writes to `syslog`, so you can see what it did with

```
grep 'test-sleep' /var/log/syslog
```