# Creating script to report system suspend or awake is not running?

Tags: 16.04, bash, suspend

Using [Is there a "variable" to see if computer is in sleep mode?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/757254/is-there-a-variable-to-see-if-computer-is-in-sleep-mode)

Here is the code that should output to a file when system goes into SUSPEND or AWAKES:

(this code is in /etc/pm/sleep.d)

(also had to make the file executable:  sudo chmod +x sleep_mode)

(when running from the command line, the "suspend script" is written to the file.

(but when I suspend the computer or awaken the computer... nothing is written to file.)

```
#!/bin/bash

# general entry 
echo "suspend script"
echo "%suspend script" >>  /tmp/suspend_time.txt
date +%s >>  /tmp/suspend_time.txt

case "$1" in
    suspend)
        # executed on suspend
        echo "%system_suspend" >> /tmp/suspend_time.txt
        date +%s >> /tmp/suspend_time.txt
        ;;
    resume) 
        # executed on resume
        echo "%system_resume" >> /tmp/suspend_time.txt
        date +%s >> /tmp/suspend_time.txt
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy your script to:

```
/lib/systemd/system-sleep/sleep_mode
```

You will need to use `sudo` powers. After copying flag it as executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/sleep_mode
```

Additionally change all occurrences of:

```
echo "%s
```

to:

```
echo "s
```

The percent sign is unnecessary.

The existing date command is OK:

```
date +%s >>  /tmp/suspend_time.txt
```

However it is formatted as number of seconds since January 1, 1970 which isn't the most readable date format.

---

### case statement

The `case` statement can be changed:

```
case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "$0: Going to $2..."
    # Place your pre suspend commands here, or `exit 0` if no pre suspend action required
    ;;
  post/*)
    echo "$0: Waking up from $2..."
    # Place your post suspend (resume) commands here, or `exit 0` if no pre suspend action required
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: made the modifications... it now enters the script on system SLEEP and AWAKE... but it does not execute either of the cases.

Comment: @jdl I've added a new section to the answer with a different case statement.

Comment: works now... thx