# Script stops running after screen lock

Tags: bash, scripts, suspend

I hope I am describing this properly.

I have a Griffin Powermate that I use to control the volume of computer.  I got it to work via this post (archived site).

```
file:///home/mspringer/Music/Griffin%20Powermate%20on%20Linux%20%7C%20screamingroot.org.html
```

I wrote this script: `pmlogin.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm /tmp/.evrouter:0
/usr/local/bin/powermate
```

I wrote this because for some reason, each time I run powermate I need to remove the `tmp` file.

Everything works fine but if after I have put my computer into suspend mode, when I unlock the screen powermate isn't working and I have to re-run the script.

My question: Why do I have to re-run it? Is there something I can change to make it persistent?

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with Cinnamon Desktop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a script when suspending/resuming? - Sony VAIO Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250690/how-to-run-a-script-when-suspending-resuming-sony-vaio-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: To be fair, OP is asking **why** this happen, not **how** to run something after suspend, so duplicate doesn't fit. Although useful as workaround.

Comment: I have seen and tried the solutions from how to run a script when suspending/resuming and with out much luck.  I will try again but part of my question is indeed why it stops with suspend/resume