# Run Script on Resume/Wakeup

Tags: scripts, suspend, hibernate

Sorry, I have to revisit this.  All the methods recommended have not worked for me. I am unsure where my error is after multiple attempts.

I have a Griffin Powemate that I use as an external volume control (don't judge me).  I want it to work after resuming from Standby/ Sleep. As it is now, I have to run a script from the command line to get it to to re-start. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with Cinnamon Desktop

The Powermate will activate and control volume if I run any of these commands from the command line - if the machine is in sleep/standby

```
pmlogin.sh
/usr/local/bin/powermate
evrouter -c /etc/evrouterrc /dev/powermate
powermate
```

If I re-power the machine, it only works if I run "pmlogin.sh"

The scripts are:

```
/home/mspringer/bin/pmlogin.sh 
    #!/bin/sh
    rm /tmp/.evrouter:0
    /usr/local/bin/powermate

/usr/local/bin/powermate
    #!/bin/sh
    evrouter -c /etc/evrouterrc /dev/powermate
```

contents of /etc/evrouterrc:

```
Window ""

    "Griffin PowerMate" "" any key/256 "XKey/XF86AudioMute"
    "Griffin PowerMate" "" any rel/7/1 "XKey/XF86AudioRaiseVolume"
    "Griffin PowerMate" "" any rel/7/-1 "XKey/XF86AudioLowerVolume"
```

/dev/powermate is a link to /dev/input/event12 - the input from the Griffin Powermate.

The "/usr/local/bin/powermate" script is from the instructions I found to make it work.  The pmlogin.sh was written by me because I had problems with the original script running after resume due to the existence of the /tmp/.evrouter:0 file.

I have followed every instruction that I could find, none of the methods have worked for me so far.  Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong or what will work?  Just an FYI, I am not a total noob, I currently run/ maintain about 5 different Ubuntu installations and have been able to solve any problem I have had.  This one I cannot resolve.

These are the basic methods I have followed, other links point me back to one or the other of these.

[how to execute a command after resume from suspend?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92218/how-to-execute-a-command-after-resume-from-suspend#92235)
[Make a script start after suspend in Ubuntu 15.04 (systemd)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661715/make-a-script-start-after-suspend-in-ubuntu-15-04-systemd?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[Run Script on Wakeup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226278/run-script-on-wakeup?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[How to run a script when suspending/resuming? - Sony VAIO Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250690/how-to-run-a-script-when-suspending-resuming-sony-vaio-ubuntu-12-04)